# PrivateRoute in React-router-dom v6 isnt working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use ProtectedRoute as
I can't see why the code isn't working, I'm not getting any error, but at `/account` it should display `<Profile/>` and it's blank, I can see the header and footer, but the whole `<Profile/>` is missing
before trying to use a `PrivateRoute`, I could display `Profile` with any problem.

my ProtectedRoute.js

```
 import React from "react";
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

    const ProtectedRoute = () => {
    const {isAuthenticated} = useSelector((state)=>state.user)
    return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
    }

    export default ProtectedRoute;
```

my app.js

```
    function App() {

    const {isAuthenticated, user} = useSelector(state=>state.user)
    React.useEffect(() => {

    WebFont.load({
      google:{
        families: [ "Droid Sans", "Chilanka"],
      },
    });

    store.dispatch(loadUser())
    }, []);
  
    return (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products/>}/>
        <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/account" element={<Profile/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginSignUp/>}/>
      </Routes>
    <Footer/>
    </Router>
    );
   }

   export default App;
```

and my Profile

```
const Profile = () => {
 const { user, loading, isAuthenticated} = useSelector((state) => state.user);

 const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuthenticated === false){
        navigate("/login");
    }
}, [navigate,isAuthenticated])
return (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title={`${user.name}'s Profile`} />
          <div className="profileContainer">
            <div>
              <h1>My Profile</h1>
              <img src={user.avatar?.url} alt={user.name} />
              <Link to="/me/update">Edit Profile</Link>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <h4>Full Name</h4>
                <p>{user.name}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Email</h4>
                <p>{user.email}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Joined On</h4>
                <p>{String(user.createdAt).substr(0, 10)}</p>
              </div>                
              <div>
                <Link to="/orders">My Orders</Link>
                <Link to="/password/update">Change Password</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Remove all the `exact` props from the routes, they aren't used or needed. Try also removing the `path` prop from the `ProtectedRoute` layout route. Are you able to inspect the DOM to see what *is* rendered? Are you sure the redux store is updated correctly?

Comment: "redux": "^4.2.0", "react-redux": "^8.0.2". I removed the path as you said and now it works, but if I refresh the page, the screen will go blank and in the console says Uncaught TypeError: user is undefined

Comment: Ok, can you share the redux code for the user state slice? The action and reducer functions?

Comment: Please share the redux slice file too

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering two routes for the same `"/account"` path. `ProtectedRoute` is rendered on its own self-closing route, so the second route rendering `Profile` is unreachable.

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products/>}/>
  <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/account" element={<Profile/>}/> // <-- unreachable, oops!
  <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginSignUp/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Remove the `path` prop from the layout route rendering the `ProtectedRoute` and ensure it is ***actually*** wrapping other `Route` components. You may as well also remove the `exact` prop on all the routes as this prop was removed in RRDv6.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Header/>
  {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
    <Route path="/products/:keyword" element={<Products />} />
    <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
    <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
      <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} /> // <-- wrapped by layout route!
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginSignUp />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer/>
</Router>
```

The `ProtectedRoute` component doesn't appear to wait for the `user` state to populate before rendering either the `Outlet` for protected content or the redirect. Apply some conditional rendering to render a loading indicator or similar while the `user` state is populated.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (!user) return null; // <-- or loading indicator, etc...

  return user.isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```